# Name for a small, art-oriented office?

Tags: phrase-requests, connotation

I have a graphic designer friend who just bought a house. There's an unused bedroom that he's converted into an office for the purpose of illustrating, designing, and other art-oriented tasks. He has a couple art tables, a Mac, some design books, and some basic art supplies in the room.

He's opposed to calling it by the term "office", though, because he feels like it evokes feelings of spreadsheets and files rather than his focus on art/design. He's also opposed to the word "studio" because it's a small, modest room and he thinks calling it a "studio" is a bit pretentious.

Is there a term that would better describe his small, modest design room?

Comment: Calling it "my home studio/office" seems perfect to me. There's nothing inherently pretentious about calling a small space a "studio." Many a great artist labored in cramped spaces.

Comment: @MarkHubbard - Saying the phrase "studio slash office" every time you want to refer to the room seems like a bit much, though. Is your recommendation to just randomly pick one of the two names?

Comment: Yes, I'd stick with "studio" and advise him to stop being modest. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Studio

Tell your friend to get over his concerns. There is no grandeur to *studio*—especially not with regard to size.

As proof, see how often the *room* appears in the NOAD definition of studio:

> 1 a **room** where an artist, photographer, sculptor, etc., works.
>
> • a place where performers, especially dancers, practice and exercise.
>
> • a **room** where musical or sound recordings can be made.
>
> • a **room** from which television or radio programs are broadcast, or in which they are recorded.
>
> • a place where movies are made or produced.
>
> 2 a film or television production company.
>
> 3 a studio apartment.

*Studio* may signify something significant with regards to quality of work put out, but not with regards to space. If his real hang up is that he doesn't believe his work is important enough to call his workplace a studio then you get to play the important role of building up his confidence. He'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

### Workroom

It doesn't have the same art focus I was looking for but is perfect in all other aspects.

- It doesn't evoke feelings of an entire art gallery or a full production studio
- It doesn't feel like it's used for filing taxes like "office" does
- It doesn't imply machinery and tools like "workshop"
- It illustrates the point of being used to get work done

Answer (score -1):

Sanctuary - too much?  The Zone? Can he be creative and actually name his room, like we do for boats?  Given it is an artistic / design room, I think naming the room could be a creative solution.